# How to send a ngfor object variable to a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a *ngFor list for my categories and inside to list i wanna show subcategories list. subcategory data coming from firebase so i querying it with category_id. My problem is i dont know how to pass category_id from html to function for every member of category.

**home.html**

```
    <ion-accordion *ngFor="let category of Categories">
      <ion-item slot="header">
        <ion-label>{{category.category_name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-list slot="content">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let category of SubCategories">
          <ion-label> {{category.subcategory_name}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-accordion>
  </ion-accordion-group>
```

**home.ts**

```
  Product: Product[] = [];
  Categories: Category[] = [];
  SubCategories: SubCategory[] = [];
  ShowSubCategories: SubCategory[] = [];
  subcategory_category_id: number;

 constructor( private dataService : DataService) {

    this.dataService.getCategories().subscribe(res =>{
      this.Categories=res;
    })

    this.dataService.getSubCategory().subscribe(res => {
      this.SubCategories=res;
    })

    console.log(this.subcategory_category_id)

  }


  getSubCategoryById(id){
    console.log(this.dataService.getSubCategoryById(id))
  }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "pass category_id from html to function for every member of category" ?

Comment: i wanna pass current {{category.category_id}} to getsubcategorybyid() function

Comment: can you add the dataService code, the function and what the console.log shows ?

Comment: Because the html display what you get from the ts file and function. Not the other way around. You normally can pass this.subcategory_category_id directly in your getSubCategoryById() function.

Comment: ```async getSubCategoryById(id){
    const subcategoryRef = collection(this.firestore, 'subcategory');
    const q = query(subcategoryRef, where("subcategory_category_id", "==", id))

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    return querySnapshot;
  }```

Comment: it shows all of the subcategories i am not sure how to show related subcategories to under the its true category

Comment: just to make sure I understand you want to make sure that your html shows a list with category1 => subcategory1, category2 => subcategory2 and so on. And category and subcategory have the same id but don't come from the same request. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes thats correct. Categories have their own collection and subcategories too. They are related to each other with category_id subsubcategory_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not clear how your data are structured, but you seem to be getting both categories and subcategories. A little work around with nested *ngFor, *ngIf and div could do the trick. Might not be the best practice :

**TS file**

```
Categories = [
{ id: 1, name: 'one' },
{ id: 2, name: 'two' },
]; 
  Subcategories = [
{ id: 1, name: 'subone' },
{ id: 2, name: 'subtwo' },
];
```

**HTML :**

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of Categories">
<ion-item>Name : {{cat.name}} | id : {{cat.id}}</ion-item>

<div *ngFor="let subcat of Subcategories">
  <ion-item *ngIf="subcat.id === cat.id">subcat id: {{subcat.id}} | subcat name: {{subcat.name}}</ion-item>
</div>
</div>
```